# Declare field outside/inside method : Sonar Singular Field Rule

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is giving me a rule violation for "Singular Field".

I have I class with only one method like this.

```
public class MyClass{

   MyType object;   

   public void myMethod(){
         object= aMethod(arg);  //Returns instance for the class MyType 
   }

}
```

Here **myMethod** is called countless times.

1. Am I saving the cost of object creation for **MyType** ?
2. Sonar is telling me to declare **MyType** inside **myMethod**().
   Does this will result in the cost of object creation?

Any explanation please....

Comment: If you create new instance of `MyType` on every `myMethod` invocation than no, you're not saving the cost of object creation. Can you show full class code?

Comment: You mean, since **aMethod** returns instance of **MyType**, it is same as creating new instance of **MyType** itself? If that is the case, I better follow Sonar Rules and make **MyType** a local one.   :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your actual code, there's strictly no need to declare `object` as a field.

Indeed, it even never needs to be accessed by another object part, so its state has no reasons to be saved (wasting slightly memory for nothing...) across program workflow.

Garbage collector could thus collect your local variable as soon as `myMethod()` finishes.

Sonar expects you to declare as follows:

```
public class MyClass{  

   public void myMethod(){
      MyType object = aMethod(arg);  //local variable instead of field ;)
   }

}
```